# Alignat: Shift entries to the right

Tags: alignat

I have the following equations:

[image]

Now I want to shift the $2^{2k}$ and $2^k$ in the last three lines to the right, just before the $\geq$ sign. How can I achieve that without hardcoding?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=12 ,BCOR = 10mm, parskip=half-, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
        \begin{alignat*}{2}
    &2^k\cdot (2^k-h)&&\geq 1 \\
    \Longleftrightarrow
    &2^{2k}-h\cdot 2^k&&\geq 1 \\
    \Longleftrightarrow
    &2^{2k}&&\geq h\cdot 2^k+1 \\
    \Longleftrightarrow
    &2^k &&\geq \sqrt{h\cdot 2^k+1} \\
    \Longleftrightarrow
    &2^k &&\geq \sqrt{n}.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

When I change 2^{2k}& to &2^{2k} I get additional space in the frst two lines.

[image]

Comment: change  `2^{2k}&` to `&2^{2k}`, also you want `\Longleftrightarrow{}` to get the correct spacing back if you have the arrow to the left of the `&`

Answer (score 3):

You want the expressions in an odd (right aligned) column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=12 ,BCOR = 10mm, parskip=half-, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
        \begin{alignat*}{2}
    &&2^k\cdot (2^k-h)&\geq 1 \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow
    &2^{2k}-h\cdot 2^k&\geq 1 \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow
    &2^{2k}&\geq h\cdot 2^k+1 \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow
    &2^k &\geq \sqrt{h\cdot 2^k+1} \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow
    &2^k &\geq \sqrt{n}.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I can use that. One more question: In your code, can I align the first two lines, so that 2^k in the first line and 2^{2k} in the second line are aligned? So that there is no space before 2^{2k}?

Comment: @Lereu you can but I wouldn't: just add another `&&` at that point just keep in mind that odd columns align right and even columns align left

Comment: @Lereu: ...replace [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) with [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) (it loads `amsmath`, but adds other functionality) and then use `\mathrlap{2^{2k} - h \cdot 2^k}\phantom{2^k \cdot (2^k - h)}`.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't try and align things that are just very loosely related.

I give you three realizations. The section titles should self-explain my recommendation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Good}

\begin{align*}
  & 2^k\cdot (2^k-h)\geq 1 \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad
  & 2^{2k}-h\cdot 2^k\geq 1 \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad
  & 2^{2k}\geq h\cdot 2^k+1 \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad
  & 2^k \geq \sqrt{h\cdot 2^k+1} \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad
  & 2^k \geq \sqrt{n}.
\end{align*}

\section{Bad (well, not so much)}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &&2^k\cdot (2^k-h)&\geq 1 \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow\quad
    &2^{2k}-h\cdot 2^k&\geq 1 \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow\quad
    &2^{2k}&\geq h\cdot 2^k+1 \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow\quad
    &2^k &\geq \sqrt{h\cdot 2^k+1} \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow
    &2^k &\geq \sqrt{n}.
\end{alignat*}

\section{Ugly}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
& 2^k&{}\cdot (2^k-h)&\geq 1 \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad
& 2^{2k}&{}-h\cdot 2^k&\geq 1 \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad
&&2^{2k}&\geq h\cdot 2^k+1 \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad
&&2^k &\geq \sqrt{h\cdot 2^k+1} \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad
&&2^k &\geq \sqrt{n}.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, I'd use `gather*` with no `\Longleftrightarrow`, explaining that each line implies the following and is implied by the preceding one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I can learn from your code. Nevertheless, I would exactly swap 1) and 3). But this is a matter of taste.

Comment: @Lereu There is a fourth realization, which I added only the picture of, with some explanation.